# C++ freeing memory of a wide character

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2005, oop

I simply cant delete my wchar_t pointer variable.
it gets initialized in the constructor by:

```
dir = new wchar_t;
```

and shouldn't I be able to delete it by:

```
delete dir;
```

The Reason for this problem seems to be an debug assertion fail.
Expression _CrtIsValidHeapPointer(pUserData)

Comment: We will need more info to ascertain what your problem is, before we can suggest a solution. What you described is certainly possible.

Comment: Yes, like what exactly prevents you from deleting it?

Comment: You are using exactly ONE wchar_t? Are you sure that `dir` is never two or more wide characters?

Comment: what is dir type? try: wchar_t* dir = new wchar_t; delete dir;

Comment: How can you tell that you can't delete it? Is an error thrown, or something?

Comment: Thank you for the many suggestions but I just found out why.
In my constructor i allocated the wchar_t pointer variable of the size of 1 wchar_t, 
but later on i wrote to it n wide letters.

Comment: Don't forget to delete it with `delete[]` not `delete`.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the heap got corrupted. This could happen, for example, if you allocate a single `wchar_t`, but write multiple characters to that pointer. Then, future interactions with the heap (such as delete) could cause errors, as assertions in the code are broken.